# Pin to start from code in windows phone apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I want the "Pin to start" functionality in my app. I don't want to create a secondary tile as in the following code:

```
StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
{
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("Red.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
    Title = "Secondary Tile",
    Count = 12,
    BackTitle = "Back of Tile",
    BackContent = "Welcome to the back of the Tile",
    BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("Blue.jpg", UriKind.Relative)
};

// Create the tile and pin it to Start. This will cause a navigation to Start and a deactivation of our application.

ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/SecondaryTile.xaml?DefaultTitle=FromTile", UriKind.Relative), NewTileData);
```

Also, I don't want the app to exit when the icon is pinned to the start screen.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there's no way to programatically pin your primary app tile to the start screen, only secondary ones. (see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/7a64bf67-ed3e-4777-be63-4f056cfeb37e/how-to-disable-pin-to-start-functionality?forum=wpdevelop))

When you create a secondary tile, the OS will automatically show the new tile on the start screen. (and deactivate your app in the process)  I'm pretty sure there's no way around this.  Sorry!